# Почему не работает скрипт собранный webpack`ом fetch is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, puppeteer

Для примера есть небольшой скрипт который работает если его запускать прям из проекта где он разрабатывается.

Он же собранный через **npm run build** не работает выдавая ошибку.

Код скрипта

```
const browserURL = "http://127.0.0.1:21223"
const url = "https://ya.ru"

const start = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
        browserURL,
        defaultViewport: {
            width: 1920, height: 1080
        },
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await await page.goto(url)

}
start()
```

Разрабатываю в **php_storm**. Если в нем же, в терминале, выполнить `node .\src\r.js` то браузер открывает **ya.ru**.

Если выполнить `npm run build` и попытаться выполнить получившийся скрипт то выдает ошибку

```
(node:3852) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Failed to fetch browser webSocket URL from http://127.0.0.1:21223/json/version: fetch is not a function
    at getWSEndpoint (d:\JS\r.js:8494:30)
    at async Object.connectToBrowser (d:\JS\r.js:8481:31)
    at async start (d:\JS\r.js:33806:21)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3852) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3852) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**webpack.config**

```
const rConfig = {
    entry: './src/r.js',
    mode: "production",
    target: "node",
    optimization: {
        minimize: false
    },
    output: {
        filename: "r.js",
        path: 'D:\\JS'
    }
}

module.exports = [rConfig]
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^10.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.52.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  }
}
```

Что происходит? Почему не работает.

Comment: расскажите, зачем вы билдите этот проект вебпаком? кстати, ваш скрипт у меня при запуске выдаёт ту же ошибку - возможно что-то незапущенное должно быть запущено? (you need to launch Chrome with the `--remote-debugging-port=21223` argument)

Comment: 1. Не могу аргументированно ответить почему вэбпак. Подскажите что либо другое?

Comment: 2. Сначала надо запустить хром вот так `chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=21223`

Comment: 1. давайте я задам вопрос иначе, - зачем вы билдите этот проект? 2. может ли быть такое, что хром или не запущен, или уже запущен и ужа занят?

Comment: 1. Собираю его что бы отдать один js файл пользователю и не тащить *npm_modules* на 400 метров туда. 2. Нет - хром запущен, если выполнить не сбилженный скрипт все работает.

Comment: Погорячился. Если из _puppeteer_ удалить хромиум то весит он 9 метров. Но все равно - собранный файл весит 300кб... не сказать что меня сильно волнует экономия места но вот перфекционизм...

Comment: puppeteer тянет за собой бинарники, собранные под ОС, так что вам не удастся избавится от него

Comment: Да я и не думал избавляться от него. Просто раньше я собирал вэбпаком все в один маленький файл и отдавал пользователю... а вот сегодня понадобилось вместо **await puppeteer.launch** приконектиться к запущенному браузеру. В первом случае нельзя использовать расширения, а они мне нужны. Так что пришлось использовать **await puppeteer.connect**. Пока отлаживал все работало прекрасно. А вот после сборки начались проблемы